# How does Haskell know which function can operate first?

Tags: haskell, infix-notation

I'm writing a custom language that features some functional elements. When I get stuck somewhere I usually check how Haskell does it. This time though, the problem is a bit to complicated for me to think of an example to give to Haskell.

Here's how it goes.

Say we have the following line

```
a . b
```

in Haskell.
Obviously, we are composing two functions, a and b. But what if the function a took another two functions as parameters. What's stopping it from operating on . and b? You can surround it in brackets but that shouldn't make a difference since the expression still evaluates to a function, a prefix one, and prefix functions have precedence over infix functions.

If you do

```
(+) 2 3 * 5
```

for example, it will output 25 instead of 17.

Basically what I'm asking is, what mechanism does Haskell use when you want an infix function to operate before a preceding prefix function.

So. If "a" is a function that takes two functions as its parameters. How do you stop Haskell from interpreting

```
a . b
```

as "apply . and b to the function a"
and Interpret it as "compose functions a and b".

Comment: So this is basically a question about the parsing of such expressions?

Comment: I can always think of some solution that deals with these kinds of problems but I really want to know how it's implemented in Haskell. Perhaps not implemented, just how it works.

Comment: I don't really understand the question?

Comment: Function application binds stronger than any infix operator.

Comment: I tried to explain my question a bit better. I really don't know how else to express myself. How do you make that infix function (the composition) operate on a and b instead of a operating on . and b?

Comment: This is a good question. I had a similar question a while back, and I also found it hard to explain my question exactly. The thing I think about now, is that the infix form of `.` is the same as the prefix form `(.)`. So when I am in doubt, I translate infix back to prefix, and since the two forms are equivalent, I can now see more clearly what is going on.

Comment: You might want to read about parsing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't put parens around an operator, it's *always* parsed as infix; i.e. as an operator, not an operand.
E.g. if you have `f g ? i j`, there are no parens around `?`, so the whole thing is a call to `(?)` (parsed as `(f g) ? (i j)`, equivalent to `(?) (f g) (i j)`).

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying that, if f took 2 functions as parameters, it still wouldn't take ? because it's an infix function?

Comment: @LukaHorvat Not because it is an infix function, but because it is an infix *name*. It is based purely on syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for are fixity declarations (see [The Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#fixity)).

They basically allow you to declare the operator precedence of infix functions.

For instance, there is

```
infixl 7 *
infixl 6 +
```

which means that `+` and `*` are both left associative infix operators.
`*` has precedence 7 while `+` has precendence 6, i.e `*` binds stronger than `+`.
In the report page, you can also see that `.` is defined as `infixr 9 .`

Comment: And in addition, function application binds tighter than any infix operator.  (And record syntax/update binds even tighter than that.)

Comment: and `:info` is useful in GHCi to check out operator fixity

Answer (score 3):

> Basically what I'm asking is, what mechanism does Haskell use when you
>   want an infix function to operate before a preceding prefix function.

Just to point out a misconception: This is purely a matter of how expressions are parsed. The Haskell compiler does not know (or: does not need to know) if, in

```
f . g
```

f, g and (.) are functions, or whatever.

It goes the other way around:

1. Parser sees `f . g`  (or, the syntactically equivalent: `i + j`)
2. Hands this up as something like `App (App (.) f) g` following the lexical and syntax rules.
3. Only then, when the typechecker sees `App a b` it concludes that `a` must be a function.

Comment: But it's lexical and syntax rules would tell it to parse it as `App (App (f (.)) g`

Comment: Not true. If this were so, then 2 + 3 would also be parsed `App (App 2 (+)) 3`  which is nonsensical.

Comment: That means Haskell obviously has to know what is a function and what isn't. Contrary to what you said before. It even needs to know the precedence if the function is in infix form.

Comment: @LukaHorvat No, this dow not follow. Look, it is so easy: If you see `a b c` it is *a applied to b applied to c*, if you see `a ° b` where ° is no varid or a varid enclosed in backquotes, it is *(°) applied to a applied to b*. (To sort out more complicated expressions, you have to know the precedence and associativity, though.) In no case, however, does it play a role whether the operands (i.e. a and b) are functions or not, as you assumed in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
(+) 2 3 * 5
```

is parsed as

```
((+) 2 3) * 5
```

and thus

```
(2 + 3) * 5
```

That is, because function applications (like `(+) 2 3`) get evaluated first, before functions in infix notation, like `*`.

Comment: I understand how and why that works. I just used it as an example of a function turning prefix when you surround it with brackets.